# Find range of the function $f(x)=\sqrt {2\{x\}-\{x\}^2}-\frac 34$

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=y$ and $\{x\}=a$

$$(y+\frac 34)^2 =2a-a^2$$

$$y^2+\frac 94 +\frac{3y}{2} =2a-a^2$$

If I had a singular $\{x\}$ term I could have simply applied the inequality $0\le \{x\}<1$
But instead I have a polynomial. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @PeterForeman I don’t think AM-GM can be applied, and the double derivative of $2a-a^2$ shows it’s decreasing (my knowledge on calculus is currently limited) . The function will be have max value for min $x$. But on putting $a=0$ and $a=1$ we get $1<a(2-a)\le 0$ which is obviously wrong

Comment: Please verify this $a-1\in [-1,0) \implies (a-1)^2 \in [1,0) \implies a^2-2a\in [0,-1) \implies 2a-a^2 \in [0,1)$

Comment: @PeterForeman yes it was a typo. So now I should just square root the interval and subtract $\frac 34$ from it?

Comment: Yes that should work. I would note that you cannot square root an interval but you can apply the fact that if $x\in[a,b]$ with $0\lt a\lt b$ we have $\sqrt{x}\in[\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}]$.

Comment: @PeterForeman just wanted to confirm, $\{,\}$ is the fractional part function

Comment: Yes this is typically the notation used for that. It just means that you have to consider the range of $f(\{x\})$ instead where $\{x\}\in[0,1)$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-x^2}-3/4$.

Comment: @PeterForeman it’s because the answers below are giving maxima has $\frac 12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint.

Your function is a bit particular : the $\{x\}$ makes it a bit more difficult to reason about.

But in fact you can just write
$f(x) = g(\{x\})$ for a certain g. and since $\{x\}$ spans over $[0;1]$ when $x$ spans over $\mathbb{R}$, you just have to study g

(Just draw it: since it is a 2nd degree polynomial, it is a parabola, and its range will appear clear on the drawing. If you don’t like drawing, just differentiate it)

Comment: I don’t follow what you are saying

Comment: Well basically you need to change your variable. Then you only have to study  $g(a) = \sqrt{2 a - a^2} - 3/4$. 
In fact you only have to study the range of $h(a) = 2*a - a^2$ since $y -> \sqrt{y} - 3/4$ is clearly monotonic. 
h is a parabola, so finding its range should be easy (just draw it to understand)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$2\{x\}(1-\{x\})$$ is non-negative and peaks at $\frac12$ (parabola).

Comment: I got the parabola in the form of $(x-1)^2=-(y-1)$. How is it non negative (i know it’s non negative by looking at it, but the parabola says it isn’t)

Comment: I didn't say that "the parabola is non-negative", did I ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate the function, you get
$$1-2x = 0 \text { or } x = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\text {Also given that } \sqrt{2x-2x^2} \text { can only be a real number if } 2x-x^2 \ge 0,$$
$$\text {The min value of } (2x-2x^2) = 0 \text { , or lower and upper bound of } x = 0,1$$
$$\text {So, } 0 \le x \le 1 \text { with maxima at } x = \frac {1} {2}$$

It is a restricted parabola.

Comment: $x$ is inside the fractional part function though